# Can't use where on a column with nil value

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have an Article model

```
Article.last.publish
=> nil
Article.last.publish != true
=> true
Article.where("publish != ?", true)
=> []
```

Why am I getting an empty array there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are only 2 falsy values in ruby : `false` and `nil`

So, if you check the value of `!nil` then the output will be `true`

So with your first statement

```
Article.last.publish     # its output is nil
```

Then your second statement

```
Article.last.publish != true  # this is correct , since !nil = true
```

But the last one

```
Article.where("publish != ?", true)
```

gets converted into a query as

```
SELECT `articles`.* FROM `articles` WHERE (publish != 1)
```

which means all articles whose publish value is not true, which means false

and false is not equal to nil.

nil and false are two different falsy values.

Comment: That makes sense, though I would expect anything that is not 1 would match != true and nil is not 1 or true.  So how would I write this where condition to match both false and nil?

Comment: I used `change_column :articles, :publish, :boolean, :default => false` and now it works fine, thanks for the information.

Comment: NULL is special in SQL - NULL = anything is false, but  NULL != anything is false too.

Answer (score 0):

Try `Article.where(publish: false)`